# What does "portal" refer to?

Tags: mortal-kombat

In *Mortal Kombat* (2021), Shang Tsung says to Lord Raiden at the end of the movie:

> Shang Tsung: No matter how many of my people you put in the ground,
> there will always be another to take their place. Today you have
> killed my warriors and you think you have won. But death is only
> another **portal**.

What does "portal" refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, "portal" refers to its common meaning, an entrance such as a door, albeit with the idea that some doors will enter, not on another room, but rather on another realm. He is stating that death, for his people, is not an end, but a transition to another world, one which they might yet fight from.

While the sentiment is often offered as a hypothetical, such as Dumbledore's statement that "To the well-organized mind, death is but the next great adventure.", here I believe it is offered as a more concrete statement that his warriors, when dead, will return to fight.